# Carbon timezone function is incorrect

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

I have the following code:

```
// $this->date_from = '11/01/2017';
// $this->date_to = '11/30/2017';

$this->where_date_from = Carbon::parse($this->date_from)->tz('America/Toronto')->startOfDay()->timestamp;
$this->where_date_to = Carbon::parse($this->date_to)->tz('America/Toronto')->endOfDay()->timestamp;
```

This produces completely innacturate timestamps. It seems to be actually subtracting double the offset from UTC.

However, when I use the following:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');
$this->where_date_from = strtotime($this->date_from.' 00:00:00');
$this->where_date_to = strtotime($this->date_to.' 23:59:59');
```

It works perfectly.

Why is this happening? I want to use Carbon to achieve this so I don't have to mess around with `date_default_timezone_set`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is running `tz`. In  fact it won't make your date will be parsed assuming given timezone but it will convert date from current timezone to timezone you gave. Assuming you have `timezone` set in `UTC` in `app.php` file (what is default), you are doing now:

```
$this->where_date_from = Carbon::parse($this->date_from, 'UTC')->tz('America/Toronto')->startOfDay()->timestamp;
```

So you assume the date is in UTC timezone and then you will convert it into America/Toronto what is obviously not what you want.

What you should do is passing timezone when parsing date like so:

```
$this->where_date_from = Carbon::parse($this->date_from, 'America/Toronto')->startOfDay()->timestamp;
$this->where_date_to = Carbon::parse($this->date_to, 'America/Toronto')->endOfDay()->timestamp;
```